# how to rotate string in assembly

Tags: assembly, rotation

How to make a simple rotation macro, that rotates left a given string.
e.g "abc" to be "bca" with 1 bytes to shift.

The logic i use:

push the first N bytes to stack

shift everything N times left

pop these N bytes to the end of string

I get the error of Invalid Effective Address. (Using NASM) indicating the invocation of the macro

```
bits 32
global main
extern puts,gets,printf

section .data
base_str: db "%s",10,0

alphabet: db "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";define english alphabet
alphalen equ $-alphabet

section .bss
buff resb 10
bufflen: equ $-buff


section .text

%macro rotatel 3
pushad
;%1=address
;%2=length
;%3=bytes to shift
    ;push N bytes to stack
    xor ecx,ecx ;zero ecx
    mov ecx,%3  ;bytes to shift

    mov eax,0
    %%lp:
        dec ecx 
        push ebx
        mov ebx,%1  ;address
        mov al, byte [ebx+ecx]  ;retrive the Nth character from string
        pop ebx
        push eax            ;save to stack
    cmp ecx,0
    jne %%lp

    ;shifts everything to left
    mov eax,0
    mov eax,%3  ;shift bytes

    mov ecx,%2  ;string length

    lea ebx, [ecx-eax]  ;calculate the end index [string length - bytes to shift]

    mov ecx,0   ;initialize counter



    %%shift_loop:
        xor edx,edx     ;zero out edx
        mov edx, %1     ;address
        add edx, ecx    ;+counter
        add edx, al     ;+bytes to shift

        mov DL, byte [edx]  ;get character from [address+counter+bytes to shift]
        push ebx
        mov ebx,%1  ;address
        mov byte [ebx+ecx], DL  ;[address+counter]=character at the right
        pop ebx

        inc ecx         ;inc index
        cmp ecx,ebx     ;if index <= end index, then loop
        jbe %%shift_loop

    ;pop N bytes from stack in reverse order
    ;ebx still holds the end index
    inc ebx     ;start index
    mov ecx,0
    mov ecx, %2 ;string length
    mov eax,0
    mov edx,0
    mov edx, %1 ;address
    %%endloop:
        pop eax     ;get character from stack
        mov byte [edx+ecx], AL
        dec ecx
        cmp ecx,ebx     ;current position <= last position
        jae %%endloop
popad
%endmacro
```

main:

```
push ebp        ;dont mess with ebp
mov ebp,esp
push ebx
push esi
push edi
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


rotatel alphabet, alphalen, 4   ;rotate left

;print with printf()
push alphabet
push base_str
call printf
add esp,4

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
pop edi
pop esi
pop ebx
mov esp,ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

Comment: Not a good algorithm. Just save the leftmost byte in a register. Shift all bytes down by 1 with a loop. Then put he saved byte in the right position.

Comment: Also, I don't believe `lea ebx, [ecx-eax]` is a valid instruction.

Comment: `[ecx-eax] ` is invalid address, you can not subtract.

Comment: ...or use `rep movsb`

Comment: movsb seems the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution. I went with movsb as advised and rotate once at a time

```
;-------------------------------------------
;MACRO: rotatel
;Description: Rotates string left for 1 time
;Modify: Only the contents of given string. All regs are saved
;Arguments: (2)
;%1: String Address
;%2: String Length
%macro rotatel 2
pushad  ;save all regs
    mov eax, %1 ;str address
    mov ecx, %2 ;str length
    dec ecx     ;we will start the source 1 forward
    push ecx
    mov DL, byte [eax]  ;get first byte from string
    mov esi, eax    ;copy to same string
    mov edi, eax    
    inc esi         ;Will copy from source which is one position forward
    cld             ;clear DF
    rep movsb       ;repeat the copy from one address to the other for length times -1
    pop ecx         ;restore ecx value
    mov byte [eax+ecx], DL  ;replace the last character
popad   ;restore regs
%endmacro
```

Comment: Perhaps slightly sweeter to have used `lodsb; mov ah,al` to fetch the first byte, which also increments `esi`.

Comment: ...and then after the main move `mov al,ah; stosb`